# glutTimerFunc() callback function isn't executed if time threshold is under a certain number of msecs

Tags: c++, callback, glut

I am working with an application which requires an engine to be executed in the lowest amount of time as possible by a GLUT GUI using the glutTimerFunc():

```
void SetGLUTTimer(void);

void callback(int value)
{
    Engine* pEngine;
    pEngine = (Engine*) value;
    pEngine->Process();

    pEngine->SetGLUTTimer();
}

void Engine::SetGLUTTimer(void)
{
    glutTimerFunc(50, callback, (int)this);
}

bool Engine::Run(void)
{
    if (m_pViewer != NULL)
        m_pViewer->Run();
    else
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

If I set the time threshold to 1000 msecs or more the engine callback will be regularly called, while any other interval below a second (like in the example above) will cause the GUI to run indefinitely never executing the engine Process() function.

Comment: You have potential undefined behavior in your code. Think about what would happen if a pointer can not fit in an `int`?

Comment: You are right, I will think of another way to manage the pointer, but that is not the reason behind the issue since the timer works fine with that callback if I set the time threshold over the second.